# Hyperbolic Geometry - Calculating curvature of hyperboloid embedded in pseudo-Riemannian manifold

Tags: manifolds, sagemath

Please go easy on me, I have just been trying to learn sagemath and one of the results I got went against my expectation. I am pretty sure this is a fairly basic math question, I am just curious where the flaw lies in my thinking.

As a toy example, I have been trying to define the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry in sagemath. The full code is in the [Jupyter Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/kloffy/22041bc1eae2185cc5b2b6be94b85939), but here is an abridged version:

First, I defined the ambient pseudo-Riemannian manifold:

```
R21 = Manifold(3, 'R^{2,1}', r'\mathbb{R}^{2,1}', structure='pseudo-Riemannian', signature=1, metric_name='g')
X21.<X,Y,Z> = R21.chart()
```

With metric:

```
g = R21.metric()
g[0,0], g[1,1], g[2,2] = 1, -1, -1
```

If I plot the pseudo-sphere, I get the two-sheeted hyperboloid (not sure if this is the easiest way to do it, but it works):

```
var('x,y,z', domain='real')
p = R21.point([x,y,z])
v = R21.vector_field(X,Y,Z,name='v')
implicit_plot3d(v.norm()(p)==1, (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3), (z,-3,3))
```

So far, this is looking very good.

Next, I define the embedded manifold:

```
H2 = Manifold(2, 'H^2', latex_name=r'\mathbb{H}^2')
H0 = H2.open_subset('H_0', r'\mathcal{H}_0' )
X_hyp.<th,ph> = H0.chart(r'th:(0,+oo):\theta ph:(0,2*pi):\phi')
```

And a differentiable map between the manifolds using the parametric equations for the upper sheet of the hyperboloid:

```
var('r', domain='real')
assume(r > 0)
Phi = H2.diff_map(R21, [
    r*cosh(th),
    r*sinh(th)*cos(ph),
    r*sinh(th)*sin(ph)
], name='Phi', latex_name=r'\Phi')
```

With metric:

```
h = H2.metric('h')
h.set(Phi.pullback(g))
```

And now for the unexpected part:

```
R = h.ricci_scalar()
```

If I calculate the curvature this way, the result is $\frac{2}{r^2}$. This is clearly positive, but isn't hyperbolic space supposed to be negatively curved? Where is the error in my thinking?

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, if I use the parametric equations for the one-sheeted hyperboloid (swap `cosh` and `sinh`), I get the expected $-\frac{2}{r^2}$.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you don't get an answer in a day or two, https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ is where more of the Sage developers (including of this package) hang out.  Good luck!

Comment: I think I am starting to make some sense out of it: In the metric that I have chosen, the two-sheeted hyperboloid given by `v.norm()(p)==1` is the "sphere" (positively curved), and the one-sheeted hyperboloid given by `v.norm()(p)==i` is the "pseudo-shphere" (negatively curved). Changing the metric to `g[0,0], g[1,1], g[2,2] = -1, 1, 1`, we get the reverse.